# What is the runtime of equals() in java.util.Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, runtime, equals

As title stated, what's the runtime of `equals()` in `java.util.Arrays` ?

For example if it's comparing two `int[]` , does it loop through every element in the array, so O(n)? And for all `equals()` in individual classes' `equals()` in java, can we assume that the runtime is always O(n) ?

Thanks.

Comment: why dont you check the source ??

Comment: In the general case, it is unspecified (because a class could have its own `equals`). However, it is a deep compare, so probably is O(n) for comparing two `int[]`

Comment: what do you mean by default equals?

Comment: @vishal_aim the default equals is defined "Two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal. In other words, two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. Also, two array references are considered equal if both are null."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As title stated, what's the runtime of default equals() in java.util.Arrays?

The default equals could mean Object.equals.  The Arrays.equals() is usually what you really want.

> For example if it's comparing two int[], does it loop through every element in the array, so O(n)?

yes, thats what the source suggests.

> And for all default equals() in java, can we assume that the runtime is always O(n)?

For some *collections* this is true, but for Tree collections it can be O(n log n). The worst case for HashMap is O(N^2) For non-collections `n` has no meaning.

Comment: Is this defined in the JVM spec, as being how to implement Array.equals(), or is the implementation left up to the particular JVM writers. i.e. will this also be true of IBMs JVM, and the Dalvik VM, or could this change in a future Oracle JVM?

Comment: @SamuelWalker While I doubt it is part of the spec, the behaviour of long standing methods don't change much on the basis that you never know what it might break if it did. In this case, it is hard to imagine why you would implement it another way esp. given you have a reference implementation.

Comment: How can it be O(n log n) for a Tree? Isn't it O(n*n log n)?

Comment: @soandos A Tree needs to make N lookups which are O(log N) each, so O(N log N)

Comment: @wvxvw For hash-maps, you'll get the worst-case O(n^2) behavior if you're very unlucky (or have an evil user) and all of your objects' hash values are the same.  In that case, you end up having no real choice but to do an n x n comparison.  hash-map equals will typically have an average runtime of O(n), but the worst-case for the obvious equality-checking implementation is O(n^2).

Comment: @wvxvw You can write a perfectly acceptable HashMap and find that your web server is under a denial of service attack because someone is deliberately trying to access all the String which would have a hashCode of 0. i.e. worst case scenarios are more likely in some situations.  TreeMap doesn't suffer from this for example.  In Java 7 you can change the hashing strategy, to avoid this ;)

Comment: @wvxvw Interesting, are you suggesting there is no such thing as a worst case O() and that hash tables which have collisions are due to a bug in the implementation of the hashtable.  If it is that simple they such just fix the bug.  Can you reference an implementation of hash table which is guaranteed never to get a collision?

Comment: @wvxvw Can you provide an implementation of any hash table which doesn't degenerate into a linked list in the worst case scenario?

Comment: @wvxvw Bloom filters?  These are used by google to enhance partitioning of search requests by sending the same sorted of requests to the same machines.

Comment: @wvxvw English is what I am known for, for the wrong reasons ;)

Comment: Peter, *Can you provide an implementation of any hash table which doesn't degenerate into a linked list in the worst case scenario*, if you mean all hash codes are exactly the same and the keys are not comparable, then no. If there are just collisions, totally possible, i.e. use trie for every collided key. Still I'd disagree, HashMap.equals is O(n) unless it's not a hash table any longer (i.e. both are degraded). Saying it's O(n^2) would imply HashMap.get(o) is O(n), itself.

Comment: @bestsss I am saying that HashMap.get() is O(n) in the worst case. e.g. when the hashCode of all the keys happen to be the same.

Comment: True, the worst case has escaped me. However only bucket based hashtable degrade into *linked* list. Open address ones degrade into array, which is still better than linked list.

Comment: @bestsss Better, but still O(n) for lookup.

Answer (score 11):

Grabbed from the source code (source code is worth 100 words :P):

```
/**
 * Returns <tt>true</tt> if the two specified arrays of ints are
 * <i>equal</i> to one another.  Two arrays are considered equal if both
 * arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs
 * of elements in the two arrays are equal.  In other words, two arrays
 * are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.  Also,
 * two array references are considered equal if both are <tt>null</tt>.<p>
 *
 * @param a one array to be tested for equality
 * @param a2 the other array to be tested for equality
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if the two arrays are equal
 */
public static boolean equals(int[] a, int[] a2) {
    if (a==a2)
        return true;
    if (a==null || a2==null)
        return false;

    int length = a.length;
    if (a2.length != length)
        return false;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        if (a[i] != a2[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This isn't the default equals.

Comment: Sorry I meant the equals in java.util.Array, not the default equals in Object

Answer (score 6):

It first checks the length, and if equal, loops over all elements and calls equals on them.

So, if you want to ignore the cost of the individual equals, yes, that would be O(n). But if the entries are Strings, for example, it will also get longer as the Strings get longer, not just as they get more (because the comparisons themselves are O(m) as well).

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28int%5b%5d,%20int%5b%5d%29): *two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order*. So it is clear that this is going to be an O(n) operation as it will need to loop over all the items (at least if they are all equal).

The [default `equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) (i.e. Object#equals) is an O(1) operation, it is a simple reference comparison:

> for any non-null reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true)